# Running a program through minikube job

Tags: yaml, minikube

I need to run a program with a parameter by making a .yaml file.

I write command kubectl apply -f test.yaml

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: o
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: o
        image: mzylowski/life-calculator:0.1
        command: ["universer(22222)"]
      restartPolicy: Never
  backoffLimit: 4
```

This is what I am trying to run "universer" with parameter "22222" for example.

This is what I get after making kubectl describe command. Pod status is "containerCannotRun".
ERROR:

```
Name:         test-d77mt
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         minikube/172.17.0.2
Start Time:   Fri, 09 Oct 2020 20:20:12 +0200
Labels:       controller-uid=9b0a6fbc-7cfc-4424-8dfb-d981b637141a
              job-name=test
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Failed
IP:           172.18.0.5
IPs:
  IP:           172.18.0.5
Controlled By:  Job/test
Containers:
  test:
    Container ID:  docker://1c82eff6e35f4f4d6ae9b7626634604ea4a2376feee893a9e40c6368cbd6cfb7
    Image:         mzylowski/life-calculator:0.1
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://mzylowski/life-calculator@sha256:af88d66777e86494164163612b7f27171f372d932c95efe006ad1b3f500e04a7
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      -universer(53822)
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       ContainerCannotRun
      Message:      OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"-universer(53822)\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
      Exit Code:    127
      Started:      Fri, 09 Oct 2020 20:20:13 +0200
      Finished:     Fri, 09 Oct 2020 20:20:13 +0200
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-rxt5c (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  default-token-rxt5c:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-rxt5c
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age   From               Message
  ----     ------     ----  ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  108s                     Successfully assigned default/test-d77mt to minikube
  Normal   Pulled     107s  kubelet, minikube  Container image "mzylowski/life-calculator:0.1" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    107s  kubelet, minikube  Created container test
  Warning  Failed     107s  kubelet, minikube  Error: failed to start container "test": Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"-universer(53822)\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

Comment: Is there any issue you encounter while running this job? It looks like correct configuration. If you see any errors please add it in your question or make it more specific.

Comment: @MariuszK. I added the errors I receive.

Comment: Issue is related to docker image you are using- can you share it?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution thanks to a friend.

This worked:

```
        command: ["universer", "22222"]
```